# Pulsars mentioned in Surah At-Tariq

Tags: surah, verses

Verse 1:3 of Surah At-Tariq talks about a star. Here's the translation of the verse 1:3 as per The Clear Quran by Dr. Mustafa Khattab;

**By the heaven and the nightly star!

 And what will make you realize what the nightly star is?

 It is the star of piercing brightness.**

**By the heaven and the nightly star!** ==> In this verse, Allah SWT swears in the name of the heavens and a nightly star.

**And what will make you realize what the nightly star is?** ==> In this verse, Allah SWT rhetorically asks Prophet Muhammad what will he know about the nightly star.

**It is the star of piercing brightness.** ==> In this verse, Allah SWT goes on to explain what the nightly star is. He explains that it is a star which is very bright.

Nowhere in the above verses it is talking about Pulsars. I checked all the translations of the above three verses and nowhere it is mentioned about the star that resembles pulsars.

When I looked more into it, it seems that the word "Tariq" is used to show that it is referring to pulsars as "Tariq" in Arabic means "morning star" or "he who knocks at the door in the morning". Other meanings include "striker", "knocker", "visitor", and "bright star" and people are referring to this particular meaning i.e. "knocker" to link it with Pulsars but it looks like making a vague try to link the Quran with scientific findings by Muslim people.

If I go by the definition of this word, "Tariq" also means "morning star" but in the Quran, it's mentioned as "nightly star", then which one is correct?

Can someone please explain how people have come to the conclusion that this verse talks about pulsars specifically? Is this true to any extent?

Comment: Which scholars? There's no shortage of random people who will make claims like this, doesn't mean they have any scholarly expertise or that it's any way related to actual Islamic teachings.

Comment: @goldPseudo : Modified the content.